# How to join two strings from different tuples but in the same index using Python?

Tags: python, ipython

The tuples inside the file:

```
 ('Wanna', 'O')
 ('be', 'O')
 ('like', 'O')
 ('Alexander', 'B')
 ('Coughan', 'I')
 ('?', 'O')
```

My question is, how to join two strings from the different tuples but in the same index with a condition?

For example in my case, i want to join string in [0] if [1] equal to 'B' and followed by 'I'

So the output will be like:

```
  Alexander Coughan
```

This is my code but the output is not like i want which is it just printed
"NONE":

```
   readF = read_file ("a.txt")
   def jointuples(sentt, i):
        word= sentt[i][0]
        wordj = sentt[i-1][0]
        nameq = sentt[i][1]

        if nameq =='I':
           temp= ' '.join (word + wordj)
           return temp

   def join2features(sentt):
        return [jointuples(sentt, i) for i in range(len(sentt))]

   c_joint = [join2features(s) for s in readF]

   c_joint
```

Comment: What does "the output is bad" mean?

Comment: Please include some more samples: What pairs would be joined because of what?

Comment: I mean the output is not like I want which is it just printed
 NONE

Comment: Despite not being exactly clear on the criteria - you have a `if nameq =='I-NP'` there... what do you expect that to do?

Comment: the pairs would be join are the string in the index[0] if the strings in index [1] is equal to "B" and follow by "I". For my case i want the output print   Alexander Coughan  @Tichodroma

Comment: Sorry, I mean if nameq == 'I' @JonClements

Answer (score 3):

Here's how I'd write this:

```
from ast import literal_eval
from itertools import tee

def pairwise(iterable): # from itertools recipes
    a, b = tee(iterable)
    next(b, None)
    return zip(a, b)

with open("a.txt") as f:
    for p0, p1 in pairwise(map(literal_eval, f)):
        if p0[1] == 'B' and p1[1] == 'I':
            print(' '.join(p0[0], p1[0]))
            break
```

---

Here's why:

Your file consists of what appear to be `repr`s of Python tuples of two strings. That's a really bad format, and if you can change the way you've stored your data, you should. But if it's too late and you have to parse it, [`literal_eval`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval) is the best answer.

So, we turn each line in the file into a tuple by `map`ping `literal_eval` over the file.

Then we use `pairwise` from the [`itertools` recipes](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools-recipes) to convert the iterable of tuples into an iterable of adjacent pairs of tuples.

So, now, inside the loop, `p0` and `p1` will be the tuples from adjacent lines, and you can just write exactly what you described: if `p0[1]` is `'B'` and it's followed by (that is, `p1[1]` is) `'I'`, `join` the two `[0]`s.

I'm not sure what you wanted to do with the joined string, so I just printed it out. I'm also not sure if you want to handle multiple values or just the first, so I put in a `break`.

Answer (score 2):

I'll extend the input data to include more `'B' + 'I'` examples.

```
phrases = [('Wanna', 'O'),
    ('be', 'O'),
    ('like', 'O'),
    ('Alexander', 'B'),
    ('Coughan', 'I'),
    ('One', 'B'),
    ('Two', 'I'),
    ('Three', 'B')]

length = len(phrases)
res = ['%s %s' % (phrases[i][0], phrases[i + 1][0])
    for i in range(length)
    if i < length - 1 and phrases[i][1] == 'B' and phrases[i + 1][1] == 'I']
print(res)
```

The result is:

```
['Alexander Coughan', 'One Two']
```

Comment: Thanks for the extra help

Answer (score 1):

here's a one line solution

```
>>> t = [ ('wanna', 'o'),
... ('be', 'o'),
... ('like', 'o'),
... ('Alexander', 'B'),
... ('Coughan', 'I'),
... ('?', 'o')]
>>> x = [B[0] for B in t if B[1]=='B'][0] + ' ' + [I[0] for I in t if I[1]=='I'][0]
>>> print x
Alexander Coughan
>>>
```

Answer (score 1):

I hadn't seen @MykhayloKopytonenko's solution when I went to write mine, so mine is similar:

```
tuples = [('Wanna', 'O'),
          ('be', 'O'),
          ('like', 'O'),
          ('Alexander', 'B'),
          ('Coughan', 'I'),
          ('?', 'O'),
          ('foo', 'B'),
          ('bar', 'I'),
          ('baz', 'B'),]
results = [(t0[0], t1[0]) for t0, t1 in zip(tuples[:-1], tuples[1:])
                          if t0[1] == 'B' and t1[1] == 'I']
for r in results:
    print("%s %s" % r)
```

This outputs:

```
Alexander Coughan
foo bar
>>>
```

If you absolutely **must** have the result returned as a string, change the list comprehension to:

```
 results = ["%s %s" % (t0, t1) for t0, t1 in zip(tuples[:-1], tuples[1:])
                               if t0[1] == 'B' and t1[1] == 'I']
```

This takes advantage of the fact that, based on your criteria, the **last** element of your list of tuples will **never** be returned as the first element of the result set.  As a result, the `zip` effectively steps you through `(tuples[n], tuples[n + 1])` so that you can easily examine the values.